ServiceStack Response filter SSE
Service stack 8.1, .net 6
Using IServerEvents in a response filter (I tried register and using attribute) the application exists with a hard error.
has exited with code 3221225477 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
This error happens when you try to notify
  public class CustomResponseFilterAttribute : ResponseFilterAttribute
  {
      public IServerEvents ServerEvents { get; set; }
      public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object responseDto) 
      {
          ServerEvents.NotifyAllAsync(res);
      }
  }

